# How to display pixel variance over time from a set of images? (brightness changing object imaged over time)

Tags: python, image-processing, heatmap, pixel, variance

I would like to display with a heat map the change in intensity/brightness over time of a set of images. These are images of a brightness-changing object imaged over time. This would be useful to see which parts of the object (which pixels) have the highest variance in brightness.

I'm currently using OpenCV to manipulate these images, but cannot find any straightforward way of getting this heatmap. In addition to this, if anyone could suggest a way of calculating the variance without having to create a separate array for the values for each pixel (maybe calculating it directly from the stack of images?) it would be helpful too.

[This in an example of what one of the images looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxf58.png)

Comment: Can you attach some source images?

Comment: which part is not straightforward? calculating variance or visualizing data?

Comment: I will upload the images as soon as I have a good set. I have found functions to calculate the variance but I wouldn't know how to apply it in a smart way, without creating an array for each pixel and then calculating the variance of that. For visualizing it, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate some synthetic data:

- All pixes change with std of 3
- Some pixes change (in shape X)  with std of 5

Code:

```
import cv2    

lena = cv2.imread("lena.png", 0)
lena = cv2.resize(dices, (100,100))

images  = np.zeros((30, *lena.shape))
images[0] = lena.astype('float64')

mask = np.rot90(np.eye(100)) + np.eye(100)

for i in range(1,30):
    img = images[i-1]    
    img += np.random.randn(*lena.shape)*3
    img += mask*5
    images[i] = img
```

The set of images created look like below

[image]

code to render images:

```
plt.close('all')
plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))

for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images[i],cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

Finally, heatmap to find the portions of the image which change at a different speed.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
ax = sns.heatmap(images.std(axis=0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

We got our mask back.

Comment: This approach works fine but is very very slow with the number of images I'm using (around 600).. Any suggestions?